# How do I make Rails index_errors match the indexes of the parameters sent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that is accepting nested attributes, and I am attempting to get the index of the nested model that fails. I have added `index_errors` to my association, and indexes are returning, but they don't match the index of the parameters sent. Here is an example (`device_actions_attributes` is the nested model in question):

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "front_desk_station"=>{"device_attributes"=>{"name"=>"New Front Desk Station", "device_actions_attributes"=>[{"label"=>"Visitor Cameraasdfasdfasdf", "action_type"=>"camera", "position"=>"0", "id"=>"16"}, {"label"=>"Visitor Cameraa", "action_type"=>"camera", "position"=>"0", "id"=>"18"}, {"label"=>"", "action_type"=>"camera", "position"=>"0", "id"=>"19"}], "id"=>"8919"}, "directory_sort"=>"alphabet", "directory_show_unit"=>"1"}, "building_id"=>"shawn-test-building-2", "id"=>"26"}
```

Notice that index 2 is the model with the error. Here is what I get back from `index_errors`:

```
#<ActiveModel::NestedError attribute=device.device_actions[0].label, type=blank, options={}>
```

Suggestions?

EDIT:
Calling the update controller action. Here are my abbreviated models:

```
class FrontDeskStation < ApplicationRecord 
  include DeviceType 
  ... 
end 

module DeviceType
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  ...

  has_one :device,
        as: :device,
        touch: true,
        dependent: :destroy
  ...
end 

class Device < ApplicationRecord 
  ... 
  has_many :device_actions, dependent: :destroy, index_errors: true 
  ... 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :device_actions 
  ... 
end

class DeviceAction < ApplicationRecord
  TYPE_VALUES = { camera: 0, call: 1, door: 2, elevator: 3 }.freeze

  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :target_device, class_name: 'Device', optional: true
  belongs_to :tenant, class_name: 'UnitsUser', optional: true

  validates :position, presence: true
  validates :label, presence: true
  validates :action_type, presence: true

  
  enum action_type: TYPE_VALUES, _prefix: true
end
```

Comment: What controller action is being called here? Please post your model code

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/48727 should provide the functionality if it is merged.